# Developing Eclipse RCP (Indigo) Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Developing RCP application for the first time and followed the steps for creating a **simple RCP application with a View**. First, create a new plug-in project *New > Other > Plug-in Project*, set the target platform to Eclipse 3.8, let the Wizard generate an Activator, tick the checkboxes "*This plug-in will make contributions to the UI*" and "*Would you like to create a rich client application: Yes*", and template i'm using is RCP application with a view.

Now, tutorials say the project will contain some generated classes like `Application.java`, `WindowAdvisor.java`, etc. However, only one class appears in my project `Activator.java`. Have i missed a step or two while creating the application?

Comment: Tutorials?  A link would be helpful to understand what you are seeing.

Comment: @jarodeells 1.http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html 2.http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html 3. http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-3/tutorial3.html 4.http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html

Comment: Have you tried installing another version of Eclipse? Maybe this one got corrupted. Or maybe downloading Eclipse Classic 3.8 instead of one of the specific ones.